# Член не является нестатическим элементом данных или базовым классом для класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть базовый класс `Being`:

```
class being
{
protected:
    std::string Name;
public:
    int strength;
    int endurance;
    int intelligence;
    int dexterity;
    float healthPoint;
    float magicResist;
    float physicalResist;
    float atackDamage;
    bool damageTypePhysical = true;
    void atack(being &being);
    void defense();
};
```

Есть производный класс `Humanlike`:

```
#include "Being.h"

class humanlike : public being
{
public:
    humanlike() : strength(5), endurance(5), intelligence(20), dexterity(8),
        healthPoint(80), magicResist(30), physicalResist(15), atackDamage(15)
    {
    }
    int luck = 15;
    int charisma = 15;
    int money = 0;
    bool run();
};
```

Мне нужно задать значения в производном классе переменным из базового, пытаюсь сделать это с помощью конструктора. Но вылазят ошибки по типу *"strength" не является нестатическим элементом данных или базовым классом для класса "humanlike"*.

Comment: Инициализировать поля класса, например strength, можно только в конструкторе этого класса.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть мне придется заново инициализировать все переменные в дочернем классе? Или как мне решить проблему?

Comment: В дочернем классе придется вызвать соотв. конструктор базового. А вообще в такой ситуации может пригодится паттерн префаб: делаете один раз экземпляр базового класса с нужными параметрами, а затем инициализируете базовый подобъект конструктором копирования.

Comment: В базовом классе по умолчанию нули. А потом вручную присваиванием.